# Android - disable touch event while scrolling

Tags: android

I tried all sorts of workarounds but none worked for me. I have a scrollview containing cells and each cell has an onclicklistener. these onclicklisteners add views to the mainview and I clear these subviews onscrollchanged. but if I try to click on these cells while scrolling with fling action, the app crashes. I tried putting the addition of views inside try catch blocks, but the exception was not caught there and the app crashed..

So I want to disable touch events when scrolling is in progress. Is there a way to do this?
The crash log is given below:-

```
12-22 13:25:34.420: DEBUG/FlurryAgent(7877): Error logged: uncaught
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2188)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9282)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2584)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2582)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2189)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:9282)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:419)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1924)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1666)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1381)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2003)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-22 13:25:34.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7877):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have 2 events, event1 and event2, and when event1 is called, it will call event2. So you want to disable event2?
in general, i usually create a variable

> isDisable = false

then override event 2 and pass isDisable to event2 somehow, assume that we were passed isDisable to event2, then the code about event1 shoule be

```
isDisable = true;
call event2
isDisable = false;
```

and inside event2, you have to check isDisable = true or false to decide call what event2 do.

Comment: no friend. That's not what I'm looking for. Let me explain it a bit better..I have 100x100 px cells inside my scrollview with clicklisteners for each cell that adds a view to the main view. Now, when I scroll the view, I don't want the views to be added in the duration of scrolling..so basically, I want to handle the event when scr9lling is in progress..

Comment: so you mean when you scroll the view, the clicklisteners for cells are called?

Comment: not exactly..I can call the clicklisteners for the cells at any point of time..but I don't want it to be called in the duration of the scroll..after the scrolling is finished, I want to be able to call the clicklisteners..I thought that this would be possible if I set a flag on the onset of scrolling and reset it after scrolling is finished..also, I can check this flag in the clicklisteners, and call them accordingly..but I couldn't find any way in which i could set or reset any flags in such a scenario..I couldn't find any listeners for the duration of scrolling..